# How to add some special values to an integer type

Tags: java

I would like to create a Java class that besides having integer types allows to have also some Enums, that is special values, a bit like Double.

Consider the case where you want to memorize an integer 0,1,100, 1000 or a special value like "0000" or "/" or "VAR";

Comment: Hi, take a look on [How to ask question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). At the moment, it is not clear what you tried and what is the issue on your end.

Comment: What would those special values mean in the context of an integer? What problems are you facing with implementing such a class (answering that might answer your implied question as well :) )?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your class has to contain those types? as in :

```
public class ExampleClass 
{ 
    // Instance Variables 
    int intTypeVar; 
    String stringTypeVar; 
    double doubleTypeVar; 


    // Constructor Declaration of Class 
    public ExampleClass (int intTypeVar, String stringTypeVar, 
                   double doubleTypeVar) 
    { 
        this.intTypeVar= intTypeVar; 
        this.stringTypeVar= stringTypeVar; 
        this.doubleTypeVar= doubleTypeVar; 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own exclusive type like this:

```
public class State {
  JUST_AN_INTEGER,
  CHEESE,
  SOMETHING_ELSE;
}

public final class MyInteger {
  private final int value;
  private final State state;

  private MyInteger(int value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.state = State.JUST_AN_INTEGER;
  }

  private MyInteger(State state) {
    if (state == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("State must be non-null");
    } else if (state == State.JUST_AN_INTEGER) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(State.JUST_AN_INTEGER + " requires a value!");
    }
    this.state = state;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    if (state != State.JUST_AN_INTEGER) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("MyValue has no value, it is of state " + state");
    }
    return value;
  }

  public int getState() {
    return this.state;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return this.value ^ this.state.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public int equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof MyInteger)) {
      return false;
    }
    MyInteger other = (MyInteger) o;
    return other.state == this.state && other.value == this.value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    if (this.state == State.JUST_AN_INTEGER) {
      return String.valueOf(this.value);
    }
    return this.state.name();
  }
}
```

This `MyInteger` can either have a normal integer value or be of one of the other states. The constructors ensure that it's only ever constructed in a consistent way (for example you wouldn't want a `JUST_AN_INTEGER` constructed without an explicit value and equally you wouldn't want a `CHEESE` state to also contain a value).

You *could* also implement the `Number` class, but that would lead to all kinds of confusing behaviour, since it doesn't act like a normal `Number` in many cases.